# Magento v. 1.9.2.4 - MYSQL Table core_email_queue still empty after Updates

Tags: magento-1.9, database, email, cron

got a strange Problem here in my Magento Installation. 
My Cron Job is running with AOE_scheduler - works fine. Cron Job is running.
Screenshot:
[image]

My MYSQL Table is still empty - no e-mails where send through the backend. no order mails, no cutsom messages to customers. nothing.

MYSQL Tables core_email_queue and core_email_queue_recipients are still empty.

[image]

Someone got an Idea what is wrong in my Magento Installation?

Thanks!!!
louis88

EDIT:
Found this in the exception.log File:

```
2016-05-11T17:08:21+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Could not read from smtp.strato.de' in /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:385
Stack trace:
#0 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php(415): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_receive(300)
#1 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(199): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(220, 300)
#2 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#3 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#4 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#5 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/controllers/Smtp/TestController.php(136): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#6 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Aschroder_SMTPPro_Smtp_TestController->indexAction()
#7 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#8 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /pages/3b/7f/d0009998/home/htdocs/magento/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your queue is getting emptied but emails are not send due to the fact that your smtp is not responding correctly. Are you using the correct port and such? Why not try default (without smtp) or via another send platform like mandrill.

Also i see several red error signs in your schedule. Whats up with those?

Comment: The Red are: Multiple tasks with the same job code were piling up. Skipping execution of duplicates. Is there a workaround to test Magento e-mail system after Upgrade - Do i can send without the CronJob?

Comment: Not really. All mails are dumped in your queue, and are only send with the cron

Comment: Ok - in my situation there is no mail stored in the mysql databse queue - do you have any idea why?

Comment: Maybe a extension conflict. what extensions are running?

Comment: where i see a full list of extensions? this could the reason

Comment: System->configuration->advanced

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/a5bJgQbA) Full List